# regex to strip all comments except within parentheses

Tags: java, regex

I have a regex that finds single and multiline comments just fine, but I want to exclude comments that are within parentheses.  I think i need a negative lookahead but have been unable to get it to work.

regex:

```
(?:/\\*(?:[^*]|(?:\\*+[^*/]))*\\*+/)|(?://.*)
```

samples of what to ignore:

```
url(data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhBgAGAIAAAOrq6v///yH5BAAHAP8ALAAAAAYzqlgoFADs=)
src: url(//:) format('no404')
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Making sure  `//` is inside a pair of parentheses is not directly possible with a Java regex. But you can take the liberty of checking whether the *next* parenthesis is a closing one (and reject the match if it is). Of course, that only works if there are no nested parentheses and no parentheses in a comment:

```
//(?![^()\\r\\n]*\\)).*
```

would do this.

As for the first part of your regex that matches `/*...*/` comments - that's a bit overcomplicated, I think. Since Java doesn't allow nested comments,

```
/\\*.*?\\*/
```

would do. You just need to make sure that the dot is allowed to match newlines in this part of the regex:

```
Pattern regex = Pattern.compile("(?s)/\\*.*?\\*/|(?-s)//(?![^()\r\n]*\\)).*");
```

Answer (score 0):

You could get away with this:

```
your_regex(?![^(]*\\))
```

ie add a negative look ahead to the end to assert that the next bracket character is not a close bracket